# Logical condition in WHERE - Incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

**Dataset:** *(Just highlighting error condition data, other conditions work fine)*

[image]

**Query:**

```
SELECT  `id`,   `uid`,  `activity_type`,    `source_id`,    `parent_id`,    `parent_type`,  `post_id`,  `status`
FROM    `user_activity` AS `user_activity`
WHERE
    `user_activity`.`activity_type` IN(
        'STATUS_UPDATE',
        'PROFILE_PICTURE_UPDATED',
        'PROFILE_COVER_UPDATED',
        'ALBUM'
    )
AND `user_activity`.`uid` = '13'
AND `user_activity`.`status` = 'ACTIVE'
-- AND `user_activity`.`parent_type` <> 'ALBUM' -- query works wihtout this condition
ORDER BY    id DESC LIMIT 10
```

The query works fine and gets the desired results, but when I add the condition:

```
AND `user_activity`.`parent_type` <> 'ALBUM'
```

query returns no results.

I don't understand what's the problem in this query.

[Here is the fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad043/2/0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL uses [three valued logic](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/). The NULL <> 'ALBUM' and NULL = 'ALBUM' both evaluate to UNKNOWN. You need to use IS NOT NULL or IS NULL to compare with nulls.

Comment: That explains the problem pretty much well.

Answer (score 3):

The `user_activity.parent_type <> 'ALBUM'` condition also filters every `NULL` value on that column, since `NULL <> 'ALBUM'` isn't `true`, is `undetermined`. So you can use something like this:

```
AND (`user_activity`.`parent_type` <> 'ALBUM' OR `user_activity`.`parent_type` IS NULL)
```

Or:

```
AND COALESCE(`user_activity`.`parent_type`,'') <> 'ALBUM'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT  `id`,   `uid`,  `activity_type`,    `source_id`,    `parent_id`,    `parent_type`,  `post_id`,  `status`
FROM    `user_activity` AS `user_activity`
WHERE
    `user_activity`.`activity_type` IN(
        'STATUS_UPDATE',
        'PROFILE_PICTURE_UPDATED',
        'PROFILE_COVER_UPDATED',
        'ALBUM'
    )
AND `user_activity`.`uid` = '13'
AND `user_activity`.`status` = 'ACTIVE'
AND IFNULL(`user_activity`.`parent_type`,'') <> 'ALBUM'
ORDER BY    id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If I consider the data in the SQLfidle, There's no problem in your query. 
The only row that it is supposed to return, following YOUR logic, is a row containing a NULL value in parent_type

MySQL logic is just diffrent than yours:
When you use the <> or != operator, the NULLs are omited and never returned.
If you want to also get the NULLs, do:

```
AND (`user_activity`.`parent_type` <> 'ALBUM' OR `user_activity`.`parent_type` IS NULL)
```

or this

```
AND coalesce(`user_activity`.`parent_type`,'whateveryouwanthere') <> 'ALBUM'
```